# Comparar colunas de um dataframe com as de outros e retirar as colunas que não forem comuns entre eles

Tags: r, data.frame

Suponha que eu tenha 3 dataframes. Neles, tenho colunas variadas (ex. x1, x2..., xn). Porém, nem todas essas colunas coexistem em todos os dataframes. Meu objetivo é comparar estes dataframes e deixar, CADA UM DELES, com as colunas em comum.

É possível executar este procedimento com apenas UMA função?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ideia base é essa, só lhe resta ciar uma função para automatizar o processo e abranger mais dataframes.

```
df1 = data.frame(x1=runif(5,0,5), x2=runif(5,5,10), x3=runif(5,0,5), x4=runif(5,10,15))
df2 = data.frame(x1=runif(5,0,5), x2=runif(5,5,10), x4=runif(5,10,15))
df3 = data.frame(x2=runif(5,0,5), x3=runif(5,5,10), x4=runif(5,10,15))

idem_cols <- intersect(intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2)), colnames(df3))

> df1[idem_cols]
#        x2       x4
#1 6.393069 12.99105
#2 7.016564 12.57616
#3 9.451348 11.62159
#4 5.728012 11.23728
#5 8.795608 13.79248

> df2[idem_cols]
#        x2       x4
#1 9.489572 12.21699
#2 7.423554 11.57359
#3 5.058671 10.75123
#4 9.319093 10.00097
#5 5.620968 14.91703

> df3[idem_cols]
#         x2       x4
#1 2.5554488 13.83610
#2 4.4639556 10.05555
#3 4.1599600 14.10665
#4 0.4610773 10.21153
#5 2.9923365 14.80820
```

Answer (score 2):

Um complemento para a reposta do @Fernandes é dado abaixo:

```
list<-list(df1[idem_cols],df2[idem_cols],df3[idem_cols])
list # cria uma lista com as colunas comuns dos dataframes

> list
[[1]]
    x2       x4
1 7.796689 14.54941
2 9.473103 14.15803
3 7.818807 10.96527
4 6.381239 14.44439
5 9.552761 12.73286

[[2]]
    x2       x4
1 5.755445 11.08562
2 8.305431 11.57553
3 7.006299 12.62098
4 7.949986 13.11914
5 6.095582 10.30344

[[3]]
     x2       x4
1 0.6701076 14.23146
2 4.5605675 11.67825
3 0.8683714 11.08652
4 2.9171325 10.14618
5 3.8379593 14.99512
```

após, cria-se um nome específico para cada dataframe através de um loop `for`:

```
for(i in 1:length(list)){
    assign(paste('df',i,sep=''),
    value=data.frame(list[[i]]))
}
```

o resultado fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

que será útil para aplicar algumas funções (como `tapply` em múltiplos dataframes).

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra função seria:

```
result<-Reduce(function(x,y)intersect(x,y),list(colnames(df1),colnames(df2),colnames(df3),colnames(df4),colnames(df5)))
```

onde pode-se comparar quantos dataframes quiser.